# Tensorflow TypeError: Can't convert 'numpy.int64' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

Here is my jupyter notebook :

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
import pickle 
import numpy as np

with open('preDF.p', 'rb') as f:
    preDF = pickle.load(f)
#pprint(preDF)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=preDF)
#df.rename(columns={166: '166'}, inplace=True)
df.head()
```

> ```
> 0 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166
> 0 3   8   1   13  15  13  9   12  12  1   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
> 1 3   1   13  15  13  9   12  12  1   27  ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
> 2 3   8   1   13  15  13  9   12  12  1   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
> 3 13  5   20  18  9   3   1   18  9   1   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
> 4 3   8   12  15  18  8   5   24  9   4   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
> 5 rows × 167 columns
> ```

```
import numpy as np 
#msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8
#train = df[msk]
#test = df[~msk]

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
train = df.iloc[train_index]
test = df.iloc[test_index]
train.columns = train.columns.astype(np.int32)
test.columns = test.columns.astype(np.int32)


import tensorflow as tf

def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    """An input function for training"""
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features.astype(np.int32)), labels.astype(np.int32)))

    # Shuffle, repeat, and batch the examples.
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)

    # Return the dataset.
    return dataset


def eval_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    """An input function for evaluation or prediction"""
    features=dict(features.astype(np.int32))
    if labels is None:
        # No labels, use only features.
        inputs = features
    else:
        inputs = (features, labels)

    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs)

    # Batch the examples
    assert batch_size is not None, "batch_size must not be None"
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    # Return the dataset.
    return dataset

def load_data(train,test,y_name=166):

    train_x, train_y = train, train.pop(y_name)

    test_x, test_y = test, test.pop(y_name)

    return (train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y)

def main(train,test):
    batch_size = np.int32(100)
    train_steps = np.int32(1000)
    # Fetch the data

    SPECIES = ['neg', 'stable', 'pos']
    (train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = load_data(train,test)

    # Feature columns describe how to use the input.
    my_feature_columns = []
    for key in train_x.keys():
        my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))

    # Build 2 hidden layer DNN with 10, 10 units respectively.
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
        # Two hidden layers of 10 nodes each.
        hidden_units=[30, 10,30],
        # The model must choose between 3 classes.
        n_classes=3)

    classifier.train(
        input_fn=lambda:train_input_fn(train_x, train_y,
                                                 batch_size),
        steps=train_steps)
    # Evaluate the model.
    eval_result = classifier.evaluate(
        input_fn=lambda:eval_input_fn(test_x, test_y,
                                                batch_size))

    print('\nTest set accuracy: {accuracy:0.3f}\n'.format(**eval_result))

    # Generate predictions from the model
    expected = ['exp neg', 'exp stable', 'exp pos']
    predict_x = {
        'open': [5.1, 5.9, 6.9],
        'high': [3.3, 3.0, 3.1],
        'low':   [1.7, 4.2, 5.4],
        'close': [0.5, 1.5, 2.1],
    }

    predictions = classifier.predict(
        input_fn=lambda:eval_input_fn(predict_x,
                                                labels=None,
                                                batch_size=batch_size))

    template = ('\nPrediction is "{}" ({:.1f}%), expected "{}"')

    for pred_dict, expec in zip(predictions, expected):
        class_id = pred_dict['class_ids'][0]
        probability = pred_dict['probabilities'][class_id]

        print(template.format(SPECIES[class_id],
                              100 * probability, expec))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
    tf.app.run(main(train,test))
```

So I get this error :

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/tmpz7rw1puj
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_task_type': 'worker', '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7f478ba9bdd8>, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_is_chief': True, '_master': '', '_session_config': None, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_evaluation_master': '', '_service': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_task_id': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_model_dir': '/tmp/tmpz7rw1puj', '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000}
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-fcd417d2c3ff> in <module>()
     98 if __name__ == '__main__':
     99     #tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
--> 100     tf.app.run(main(train,test))

<ipython-input-141-fcd417d2c3ff> in main(train, test)
     64         input_fn=lambda:train_input_fn(train_x, train_y,
     65                                                  batch_size),
---> 66         steps=train_steps)
     67     # Evaluate the model.
     68     eval_result = classifier.evaluate(

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    350 
    351     saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 352     loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    353     logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    354     return self

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    810       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
    811       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
--> 812           features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
    813 
    814       if self._warm_start_settings:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
    791 
    792     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
--> 793     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
    794     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
    795 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py in _model_fn(features, labels, mode, config)
    352           dropout=dropout,
    353           input_layer_partitioner=input_layer_partitioner,
--> 354           config=config)
    355 
    356     super(DNNClassifier, self).__init__(

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py in _dnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode, head, hidden_units, feature_columns, optimizer, activation_fn, dropout, input_layer_partitioner, config)
    183         dropout=dropout,
    184         input_layer_partitioner=input_layer_partitioner)
--> 185     logits = logit_fn(features=features, mode=mode)
    186 
    187     def _train_op_fn(loss):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py in dnn_logit_fn(features, mode)
     89         partitioner=input_layer_partitioner):
     90       net = feature_column_lib.input_layer(
---> 91           features=features, feature_columns=feature_columns)
     92     for layer_id, num_hidden_units in enumerate(hidden_units):
     93       with variable_scope.variable_scope(

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py in input_layer(features, feature_columns, weight_collections, trainable, cols_to_vars)
    271   """
    272   return _internal_input_layer(features, feature_columns, weight_collections,
--> 273                                trainable, cols_to_vars)
    274 
    275 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py in _internal_input_layer(features, feature_columns, weight_collections, trainable, cols_to_vars, scope)
    192       ordered_columns.append(column)
    193       with variable_scope.variable_scope(
--> 194           None, default_name=column._var_scope_name):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    195         tensor = column._get_dense_tensor(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    196             builder,

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py in __enter__(self)
   1901 
   1902     try:
-> 1903       return self._enter_scope_uncached()
   1904     except:
   1905       if self._graph_context_manager is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py in _enter_scope_uncached(self)
   2006         raise
   2007       self._current_name_scope = current_name_scope
-> 2008       unique_default_name = _get_unique_variable_scope(self._default_name)
   2009       pure_variable_scope = _pure_variable_scope(
   2010           unique_default_name,

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py in _get_unique_variable_scope(prefix)
   1690   var_store = _get_default_variable_store()
   1691   current_scope = get_variable_scope()
-> 1692   name = current_scope.name + "/" + prefix if current_scope.name else prefix
   1693   if var_store.variable_scope_count(name) == 0:
   1694     return prefix

TypeError: Can't convert 'numpy.int64' object to str implicitly
```

My guess is that this worked without calling numpy as a simple example.

now that I've called numpy every int is a int64 and it seems that tensorflow try to convert very simply an int to string.

But as it is not so simple to convert an int64 to a string it failed because now all int are by default int64.

But I have some problems to find which int is problematic here.

The notebook is here :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rx8v5aap3zhoshm/NewML.html?dl=1
and the pickle predf is here : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wd831906jq3o1jl/preDF.p?dl=1

Comment: It would be helpful if you try to create an [mcve] here. That means try to remove stuff (incrementally) from your data and code that shows the same problem until you can't remove anything anymore. Removing stuff doesn't necessarily mean just deleting lines but also replacing unnecessary calls with "stub data" and/or constants. Typically the script and data is not longer than 10-20 lines and you'll get much better answers (or any at all) and the question will also be more helpful for future visitors.

Comment: The 2nd cell in your notebook has missing variables? Can you please provide a notebook which works. Also try adding `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)` after loading the dataframe in the first cell and see if it fixes the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the column names as string and try.

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

Comment: Yes it was the type thanks :) I've resolved it by my self but promised a bounty so enjoy it and thanks :)